# How can I send livestream to YouTube using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube-data-api

You may know the software called OBS studio: by only knowing the live stream key, it sends live stream to YouTube.

I am supposing that it is using some kind of YouTube API to do that. If that's the case what is that API? Can I use this with Node.js?

Comment: [YouTube Live Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started). As to being able to use node.js, I'm sure you will be able to code something up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google offers an API that is quite reach of features: 
[YouTube Live Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/).

You may begin your journey by reading the official getting started doc: [YouTube Live Streaming API Overview](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started). Then I recommend absorbing these two important documents: [Life of a Broadcast](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/life-of-a-broadcast) and [Understanding Broadcasts and Streams](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/broadcasts-and-streams).

Depending of the type of application you intend to develop (desktop app or server-side web app), you need to get acquainted with the so-called OAuth 2.0 authentication/authorization flows (since all the endpoints of this API require OAuth): [OAuth 2.0 Flow: Installed apps](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/guides/auth/installed-apps) or [OAuth 2.0 Flow: Server-side web apps](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps).

For what concerns Node.js, Google has made available a client library: [Google API Client Library for Node.js (alpha)](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/); and also some [Node.js sample code](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/tree/master/samples), that, unfortunately, does not yet include programs exercising the Live Streaming API.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [YouTube Live Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started). It is an HTTP-based API, so you will be able to access it from Node.js as well as basically any other programming language capable of making HTTP-requests.